# Why does $\int_{0}^{b}{1\over(1+x)x^a}$ converge when 0<a<1 for fixed b>0?

Tags: calculus

It is obvious that $\int_{0}^{b}{1\over(1+x)x^a}$ diverges when $a = 1$ for any fixed positive constant $b$.

However, whenever I calculate the integral with $a<1$, the integral converged, regardless of how $a$ is close to 1, I don't know why.

I tried to find the function larger than ${1\over x^a(1+x)}$, whose integral in the interval (0,b) converges, but It failed.

Is it true that $\int_{0}^{b}{1\over(1+x)x^a}$ converges for fixed positive $b$?
If it is, How could we prove that?

Comment: $\frac 1 {(1+x)x^{a}}<\frac  1{x^{a}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that $b < 1$—clearly any integral in the range $[1, b']$ with $b' > 1$ is bounded, so does not affect the finiteness. Then, $1/(1+x) \in [1/2, 1]$—in particular, it's bounded, so also does not affect the finiteness.

Thus, it suffices to show that $\int_0^1 x^{-a} < \infty$ for $a < 1$. Given that you know this integral is infinite for $a = 1$, I'm guessing that you know that it is finite for $a < 1$.

In fact, you can take $b = \infty$ and still get finiteness provided also $a > 0$. I leave that to you with just a hint: "$x+1$ is approximately $x$ when $x$ is large".